# Is there any tools like SQL Server Profiler for Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I know that Cassandra has logging features like by enabling debug mode we can see details,
or by the means of JMX we can explore objects of Cassandra , but Is there any tools like SQL Server Profiler , which can monitor queries and filter them as i want?

Comment: I'd love to see a tool like this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra's built in [tracing](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-request-tracing-in-cassandra-1-2) mechanism is the closest things that exists in the Cassandra world.

DataStax Enterprise also includes an audit [logging](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.0/security/data_auditing) mechanism the could be useful as well.